# I want display Full page width ReactTable

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KaJ0.png)

I want to remove that space from right side of my table,now im using ReactTable to display my data here my table displaying like some leftside so if I see my full table then I should scroll my page so I want to Remove unwanted space from my table

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactTable from "react-table-6";
import '../assets/test.css'

import 'react-bootstrap'
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { DateRangePicker } from 'rsuite';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; 
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; 




function ReportTable({viewReportClicked}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const [redeemedOnDate, setRedeemedOnDate] = useState(null);
  const [expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState(null);
  
  
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3005/BhimaGCReport").then((response) => {
      let filteredData = response.data;
       console.log(filteredData);
      if (selectedDate) {
        const [startDate, endDate] = selectedDate;
        const startString = startDate.toISOString();
        const endString = endDate.toISOString();
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((row) => {
          const date = new Date(row.DateAtClient);
          return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
        });
      }
  
      if (redeemedOnDate) {
        const [startDate, endDate] = redeemedOnDate;
        const startString = startDate.toISOString();
        const endString = endDate.toISOString();
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((row) => {
          const date = new Date(row.RedemptionDate);
          return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
        });
      }
  
      if (expiryDate) {
        const [startDate, endDate] = expiryDate;
        const startString = startDate.toISOString();
        const endString = endDate.toISOString();
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((row) => {
          const date = new Date(row.Expirydate);
          return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
        });
      }
      
      if (redeemedOnDate) {
        const [startDate, endDate] = redeemedOnDate;
        const startString = startDate.toISOString();
        const endString = endDate.toISOString();
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((row) => {
          const date = new Date(row.RedemptionDate);
          const expiryDate = new Date(row.Expirydate);
          return date >= startDate && date <= endDate && date <= expiryDate;
        });
      }
      setData(filteredData);
    });
  }, [selectedDate, redeemedOnDate, expiryDate]);
  

  const cardTypes = useMemo(() => [...new Set(data.map((row) => row.CardType))], [data]);
  const statusTypes = useMemo(() => [...new Set(data.map((row) => row.TransType))], [data]);
   
  
   const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
   currency: "INR",
  });
  
  
  
  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "GC No",
      accessor: "CardNumber",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120, // Fixed width of 120 pixels
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Footer: <span><strong>Total Cards:</strong> {numberFormat.format(data.length)}</span>,
      Cell: ({ value, row }) => {
        const redeemedOn = new Date(row.RedemptionDate);
        const expiry = new Date(row.Expirydate);
        const issuedate = new Date(row.DateAtClient);
        const redeemedCount = parseInt(row.RedeemedCount);
        const redemptionAmt = parseFloat(row.RedemptionAmt);
        const  activationAmt = parseFloat(row.ActivationAmt);
        if (redeemedOn > expiry || redeemedOn < issuedate || redeemedCount > 1 || activationAmt < redemptionAmt  ) {
          return <div style={{ color: "red",fontWeight:"bolder"}}>{value}</div>;
        } else {
          return <div>{value}</div>;
        }
      },
    },
    
    {
      Header: "ActivatedOn",
      accessor: "DateAtClient",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
        return (
          <DateRangePicker
            placeholder="Select Date Range"
            value={filter && filter.value}
            onChange={(value) => {
              setSelectedDate(value);
              onChange(value);
            }}
          />
        );
      },
      Cell: ({ value }) => {
        const date = new Date(value);
        return <span>{`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`}</span>;
      },
    },
    {
      Header: "CardType(Physical/Digital)",
      accessor: "CardType",
      filterable: true,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
       Cell: ({ value }) => {
          if (value === "Bhima Gift Card") {
            return <span>P</span>;
          } else if (value === "Bhima Jewellers e-Gift Card") {
            return <span>D</span>;
          } else {
            return <span>-</span>;
          }
        },
     
      
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => (
        <select
          onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          value={filter ? filter.value : ""}
        >
          <option value="">All</option>
          {cardTypes.map((cardType) => (
            <option key={cardType} value={cardType}>
              {cardType}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      ),
      width:120,
      Footer: <span><strong>Total CardTypes: </strong>{cardTypes.length}</span>
    },
    {
      Header: "CardValue",
      accessor: "ActivationAmt",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Footer: <span><strong>Sum:</strong> {numberFormat.format(data.reduce((total, row) => total + row.ActivationAmt, 0))}</span>
      
    },
    {
      Header: "Expirydate",
      accessor: "Expirydate",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
    
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => (
        <DateRangePicker
          placeholder="Select Date Range"
          value={filter && filter.value}
          onChange={(value) => {
            setExpiryDate(value);
            onChange(value);
          }}
        />
      ),
      Cell: ({ value }) => {
        const date = new Date(value);
        return <span>{`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`}</span>;
      },
    },
    {
      Header: "RedemedOn",
      accessor: "RedemptionDate",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => {
        return (
          <DateRangePicker
            placeholder="Select Date Range"
            value={filter && filter.value}
            onChange={(value) => {
              setRedeemedOnDate(value);
              onChange(value);
            }}
          />
        );
      },
      Cell: ({ value }) => {
        const date = new Date(value);
        return <span>{`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`}</span>;
      },
    },
    {
      Header: "RedemedAt",
      accessor: "RedemptionBranch",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Footer: ({ data }) => {
        const branches = [...new Set(data.map((d) => d.RedemptionBranch))];
        return <span><strong>Total Branches:</strong> {branches.length}</span>
      },
    },
    
    
    {
      Header: "Redemed Amount",
      accessor: "RedemptionAmt",
      filterable: true,
      width:120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Footer: <span><strong>Sum: </strong>{numberFormat.format(data.reduce((total, row) => total + row.RedemptionAmt, 0))}</span>,
    },
    {
      Header: "RedemedInvoiceNo",
      accessor: "RedemptionInvoiceNo",
      filterable: true,
      width: "auto",
      headerClassName: "header-color"
    },
    {
      Header: "Status(Active/Redem)",
      accessor: "TransType",
      filterable: true,
      width: 120,
      headerClassName: "header-color",
      Cell: ({ value }) => {
        if (value === "Card Activate") {
          return <span>A</span>;
        } else if (value === "Redeem Card") {
          return <span>R</span>;
        } else if (value === "eGiftissue") {
          return <span>E</span>;
        } else {
          return <span>{value}</span>;
        }
      },
       
      Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => (
        <select
          onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          value={filter ? filter.value : ""}
        >
          <option value="">All</option>
          {statusTypes.map((TransType) => (
            <option key={TransType} value={TransType}>
              {TransType}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      ),
    

    },
    
    
  ];

  const tableRef = useRef();

  const csvData = useMemo(() => {
    const headers = columns.map((col) => col.Header);
    const datad = data.map((row) => {
      const obj = {};
      columns.forEach((col) => {
        obj[col.Header] = row[col.accessor];
      });
      return obj;
    });
    return datad;
  }, [data, columns]);

  
  
  
  return (
    <div className="table-container">
      
    <div className="table-heading">
      <i className="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    

      {viewReportClicked && <h2 className="report-heading" style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '20px', margin: '0 auto 20px'}}>Bhima GiftCard Report</h2>}
      </div>
      <div className="button-wrapper">
        <CSVLink color="green" data={csvData} filename="Giftcardreport.csv"style={{width:"6%", color:"white"}} className="btn btn-primary">
          Export CSV
        </CSVLink>
        
        <ReactToPrint
          trigger={() => <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{ marginLeft: "89%",width:"5%" }}>Print</button>}
          content={() => tableRef.current}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ overflowX: "auto" }}>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          style={{
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
          }}
          hieght={400}
          minRows={0}
          showPagination={true}
          sortable={true}
          resizable={false}
          noDataText="No data available"
          defaultPageSize={25}
          pageSizeOptions={[25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000]}
          filterable={true}
        />
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default ReportTable;
```

```css
@import "rsuite/dist/rsuite.css";

#root{ padding: 1px; }
  

table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width:initial;
  }
  h2{
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th:last-child,
  .ReactTable .rt-tfoot .rt-td:last-child {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  .ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th:last-child,
  .ReactTable .rt-tfoot .rt-td:last-child,
  .ReactTable .rt-tbody .rt-td:last-child {
    width: 10%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  
  .table-heading {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  
  .table-heading i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
    
 
  
  /* .table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  } */
  
  .ReactTable {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border: none;
      height: 100%;
     border-spacing: 0;
     display: block;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 0;
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
   
  }
 
  .ReactTable .rt-thead .rt-th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: auto;
    background-color:thistle;
  }
  .ReactTable .rt-tbody {
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    font-style:initial;
    font-size: 10.5px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
  }
  
  .ReactTable .rt-tbody .rt-td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
   
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  
  .pagination {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .pagination li {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  
  .pagination li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .pagination li.active a {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }

  .table-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

    
 
  
  th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .headerTable{
    background-color: #e8edf2;
    padding: 100px 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1c2229;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
 
  

  .showPagination {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin-left: 0.2em; 
   border: 1px solid #666666; 
   justify-content: center;
   width: 100%;
  }
  .my-pagination {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .rt-table table-striped table-hover {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .table {
    background-color:brown;
  }
  .header-color {
    color:#1c2229;
    background-color:brown;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .report-heading {
    border: 5px solid rgb(94, 3, 3);
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 150%;
    color:#333;
  }
  .total-cards {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color:saddlebrown;
  }
 
  .react-table-6 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  
  .react-table-6 .rt-table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .react-table-6 .rt-thead {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .react-table-6 .rt-thead .rt-th:last-child,
  .react-table-6 .rt-tbody .rt-td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .report-table-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .table-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .ReactTable {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .ReactTable {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

now I'm my table contain some unwanted space right side of my table I want remove that

I want to remove that space and display my table in full page without scrolling my page

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what you are trying

Comment: It would help us help you if you provided a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with only the lines of code pertinent to the problem, instead of pasting this much code and hoping someone is patient enough to read through all of them.